# How can i test my Facebook Login button on my Android App?

Tags: android, kotlin, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I would like to test my Facebook Log in button (on my android APP), the problem is when i click the button it shows me the facebook window but it says that the app its not active (which is obvious, its on development)
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/za77f.jpg)
How i can i test the button when is on develpment? i have to do something special on the code / Facebok site?

I tried moving some things on the facebook site but its not working, someone knows how to do that? The page its not really clear about specific things like this

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the answer, i was trying to press the button with a logged account on the facebook app, that account had no permissions (to try the app in development mode), and thats why the error, the solution was **log out first** and use a test user(provided by the facebook page), hope it helps to other people! :)